# How to globally listen to actionevents

Tags: java, jsf-2

Is it possible to register a global actionlistener, that will listen to all action events being fired on a page?

If so, thats would mean I don't need to register the same (default) actionlister on every action component.

Comment: Why not simply use always the same `actionListener="#{sameBean.sameListener}"` for every component, you will be able to get the sender with **ActionEvent**. I still don't understand why you want to do so...

Comment: can you tell me exactly what you are trying to do? Just want to know the idea...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I would like to keep my code clean and possibly I may need another actionlistener for a component.

Comment: @FahimParkar I'm trying to figure out from which part of the page the action originated

Answer (score 0):

There is two way you can do it :

Using `actionListener` parameter :

```
<h:commandButton id="test1" value="Test 1" actionListener="#{bean.action}" />
<h:commandButton id="test2" value="Test 2" actionListener="#{bean.action}" />


public void action(ActionEvent event)
{
    System.out.println(event.getComponent().getClientId());
}
```

Using normal parameter :

```
<h:commandButton id="test1" value="Test 1" actionListener="#{bean.action('test1')}" />
<h:commandButton id="test2" value="Test 2" actionListener="#{bean.action('test1')}" />

public void action(String sender)
{
    System.out.println(sender);
}
```